# ggplot axis order (factor) changes when using last_plot()

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I've been able to successfully create a dotpot in ggplot for percentages across gender. But, I want to highlight the significant differences. I thought I could do this with a combination of subsetting and the use of last_plot().

Here’s my data:

```
require(ggplot2) 
require(reshape2)

prog <- c("Honors", "Academic", "Social", "Media")
m <- c(30,35,40,23)
f <- c(25,40,45,15)
s <- c(0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.03)
temp <- as.data.frame(cbind(prog, m, f, s), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

first <- temp[,1:3]
first.melt <- melt(first, id.vars = 'prog', variable.name = 'Gender', value.name = 'Percent')
first.melt <- as.data.frame(cbind(first.melt,temp[,4]), , stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(first.melt) <- c("program", "Gender", "Percent", "sig")
first.melt$program <- as.factor(first.melt$program)
```

Here’s where I reverse order my Program variable, so that when graphed if will be alphabetical from top to bottom.

```
first.melt[,1] = with(first.melt, factor(first.melt[,1], levels = rev(levels(first.melt[,1]))))
first.melt$sig <- as.numeric(as.character(first.melt$sig))
first.melt$Percent <- as.numeric(as.character(first.melt$Percent))
```

Now, I subset...

```
first.melt.ns <- subset(first.melt,sig > 0.05)
first.melt.sig <- subset(first.melt,sig <= 0.05)

ggplot(first.melt.ns, aes(program, y=Percent, shape=Gender)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("m"=1, "f"=5))
```

The first run at ggplot get’s me my non-significant Program pairs – and it’s in the right order – so, I add my the two new points for male and female (making them solid, to draw attention as a significant pair):

```
last_plot() + 
  geom_point(data=first.melt.sig, aes(program[Gender=="m"], y=Percent[Gender=="m"]), size=3, shape=19) + 
  geom_point(data=first.melt.sig, aes(program[Gender=="f"], y=Percent[Gender=="f"]),size=4, shape=18)
```

The points get added just fine – ggplot works. But notice my Program axis – it’s correct, but reversed now.

Comment: You do realize that `cbind(...)` operation made that an all character matrix, right

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat - I did once joran pointed out the benefits of data.frame. Do you think the cbind operation was what was causing the change in the axis? Or was your comment more of a "heads-up?"

Comment: The latter. @joran's comment didn't seem to have caused you to make an edit, and I was trying to explain the source of some potential problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you really should avoid `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`. It is dramatically increasing the amount of work necessary to prepare your data. The function for creating data frames is (naturally) `data.frame`. Use it!

What you're doing here is basically trying to get around the limitation of only having one shape scale. It's probably easiest to just do this:

```
temp <- data.frame(prog,m,f,s)
first <- temp[,1:3]
first.melt <- melt(first, id.vars = 'prog', variable.name = 'Gender', value.name = 'Percent')
first.melt$sig <- rep(temp$s,times = 2)
first.melt[,1] = with(first.melt, factor(first.melt[,1], levels = rev(levels(first.melt[,1]))))

first.melt.sig <- subset(first.melt,sig < 0.05)
first.melt$Percent[first.melt$sig < 0.05] <- NA

ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = first.melt,aes(x = prog,y = Percent,shape = Gender),size = 3) + 
    geom_point(data = first.melt.sig[1,],aes(x = prog,y = Percent),shape = 19) +
    geom_point(data = first.melt.sig[2,],aes(x = prog,y = Percent),shape = 18) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    scale_shape_manual(values=c("m"=1, "f"=5))
```

In general, work to structure your `ggplot` code so that you're subsetting data frames, *not* variables inside of `aes`. That gets both tricky and dangerous, because `ggplot` is assuming certain things about what you pass inside of `aes` in order for the evaluation to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for this - and the advice. It's hard to break things that you learned a while ago. I had a follow-up: because the line numbers may change in the first.melt.sig data frame (as different runs may produce different significance values), would you recommend changing "data = first.melt.sig[1,]" to "data = first.melt.sig[ which(first.melt.sig$Gender == "m"),]"? Or is using which in the ggplot data call not good?